# Using Varnish with multiple named vhosts using regex

Tags: regex, varnish-vcl

I'm implementing Varnish (4.0) for a server with lots of named virtual hosts. Using a name
convention would make configuration easy. I want rename foo.com to foo.myhost.com.

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "foo.com") {
        set req.http.host = "foo.myhost.com";
    } 
    set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "(*.).com$","\1.myhost.com");
}
```

I cant get the regular expression right.

Comment: `(*.).com$`should be `(.*?)\.com$`

Comment: Noop, thanks but I still got an error.

Comment: Doesn't catch or doesn't change?
What does the error say?